# Android querying data from azure mobile services

Tags: java, android, azure, insert

I am fine with inserting data into azure mobile services, however I am having trouble querying the data once I input it.

This is how I am inserting data into azure mobile services and it works fine:

```
public class Register extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1 && password.equals(con)) {
                    Log.d("User Created!", json.toString());
                        // Save new user data into Parse.com Data Storage
                        ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
                        user.setUsername(username);
                        user.setPassword(password);
                        user.setEmail(email);
                        final Item myItem = new Item();
                        myItem.id = username;
                        myItem.text = "Test Program";
                        myItem.complete = false;
                        final MobileServiceTable<Item> mToDoTable = mClient.getTable(Item.class);
                         new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                                @Override
                                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                                    try {
                                        mToDoTable.insert(myItem).get();
                                        } catch (Exception exception) {

                                    }
                                    return null;
                                }
                            }.execute();
```

this is my attempt for querying the data which does not work as log prints "not working" each time

```
public class LoginSignupActivity extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    try {
                     MobileServiceTable<ToDoItem> mToDoTable = mClient.getTable("Item", ToDoItem.class);
                        final MobileServiceList<ToDoItem> result =
                            mToDoTable.where().field("id").eq("myemail@domain.com").execute().get();
                        for (ToDoItem mToDo : result) {
                            Log.d("yes", "working");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception exception) {
                     Log.d("not", "working");
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            }.execute();
```

Comment: Can you log the exception in your catch statement and post it here?

Comment: @Tomislav output says "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: @Tomislav I edited the post, maybe the error lies in the fact that I am trying to retrieve data from another class?